# Confused on how to make a simple drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I've been looking at some guides and it didn't work out. Whenever I try to hover over my items, it changes the position of the main `<li>`. I'm trying to make it so whenever I hover over it, it will drop down and show me A,B, and C.

Here's my code:

#### HTML:

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li>
        <a href="info.html">Info</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="members.html">Members</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="hikikomori.html">A</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="akashiia.html">B</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="munkyuke.html">C</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS:

```
#navbar{
    background-color: #404040;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 10%;
}
#navbar li{
    display: block;
    padding: 30px;
    float: right;
}
#navbar li a{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666666;
}
#navbar li a:hover{
    color: #999999;
}
#navbar li:hover{
    background-color: #8c8c8c;
}
#navbar li ul li{
   display:none;
}
#navbar li:hover ul li{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplest example with your code.

```css
#navbar{
    background-color: #404040;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;

}
#navbar li{
 padding: 30px;
    float: right;
}
#navbar li a{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666666;
}
#navbar li a:hover{
    color: #999999;
}
#navbar li:hover{
    background-color: #8c8c8c;
}
#navbar li ul{ /* modified*/
   display:none;
   background:red;
   padding:0px;
   margin-left:-50px;
}
#navbar li ul li{ /* added */
 float:none
}
#navbar li:hover ul{
    display:block;
 position:absolute; /* added */
 }
.clearfix{clear:both}
```

```html
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="members.html">Members</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="hikikomori.html">Aern</a></li>
            <li><a href="akashiia.html">Belvne</a></li>
   <li><a href="munkyuke.html">CodeRemeos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 <div class='clearfix'></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: yeah this code works somehow, but im still having problems, when i hover over it the background collor of the box itself is aligned wrong, like u can see that the left width of it it's somehow more then it's suppose to be. i tried editing the width of it but it won't work.

Comment: you have to adjust the margin in `#navbar li ul{ /* modified*/
   display:none;
   background:red;
   padding:0px;
   margin-left:-50px; /*adjust the margin*/
}`

or if you do not want to use negative margin, remove the margin and add the `left:0px` in `#navbar li:hover ul{` this will set the dropdown to left. To align it with the parent menu-item add `position:relative` in `#navbar li{`. Hope this help.

Comment: Yep perfect i made margin-left:-30; and then added a width do it 138px; and it's now showing as i want it to, and nothing is overlapping or anything. thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Add these lines to your css to force the hovered `<a>` to stay aligned to the right.

```css
#navbar>li:hover>a{
  display:block;
   text-align:right; 
}
```

and edit the `#navbar li{...}` property to correctly display the submenu (by applying float only to main menu elements)

```css
#navbar>li{
  float:right;
}
#navbar li{
  display: block;
  padding: 30px; 
}
```

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qrpjfsdg/2/